# Android Studio - Execution failed for task compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-task

I opened an old project separated into 6 modules with `Android Studio` but it always fails in the building task.
My ENV is :

```
Ubuntu 14.04
OpenJDK7
Android Studio 2.2 preview 2
```

It was failing in the build for most of the modules and telling me that it can't find a Java Complier, Here you are the error trace :

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':maskable_layout:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I was sure that I have JDK installed on my machine and I tried to install `Oracle Java` and modified `JAVA_HOME` in my profile file `.bachrc` but the error didn't disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to get back to the old version of `Android Studio 2.1`.
It seems to be a problem with the new `Android Studio` and it's working fine with me on the old version now.

Comment: I'm using 1.5 and having the same problem